# AnimationDrawable Pause ?

Tags: android

Hello I was trying to Pause Animation Drawable but could not succeeded. With the help of stack overflow I atleast got the help of animationDrawable end listener here is the code for it . IS there any possible way where I can pause the animation Drawable and Start it from where it has paused ...

```
public abstract class CustomAnimationDrawable extends AnimationDrawable{

    /** Handles the animation callback. */
    Handler mAnimationHandler;
    Runnable r= new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               onAnimationFinish();
        }
    };

    public CustomAnimationDrawable(AnimationDrawable aniDrawable) {
        /* Add each frame to our animation drawable */
        for (int i = 0; i < aniDrawable.getNumberOfFrames(); i++) {
            this.addFrame(aniDrawable.getFrame(i), aniDrawable.getDuration(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        /*
         * Call super.start() to call the base class start animation method.
         * Then add a handler to call onAnimationFinish() when the total
         * duration for the animation has passed
         */
        mAnimationHandler = new Handler();
        mAnimationHandler.postDelayed(r, getTotalDuration());

    }

    /**
     * Gets the total duration of all frames.
     * 
     * @return The total duration.
     */
    public int getTotalDuration() {

        int iDuration = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumberOfFrames(); i++) {
            iDuration += this.getDuration(i);
        }

        return iDuration;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the animation finishes.
     */
    abstract void onAnimationFinish();

     public void destroy()
    {


         mAnimationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(r);
         mAnimationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);


    }
```

}

Kindly please help is there any way i can pause ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been looking around, and it doesn't seem that there's a way to directly do it. All of the variables and methods for setting the frame in AnimationDrawable are private. However, you can get the index of the frame the animation is on when you hit pause and then create a new animation by iterating through the original animation from the index of the last frame played (and then start over and add the rest if the animation is cyclical).

I started out with an XML based animation loop, and then just added another one for pause and resume. Here's what I ended up doing, and it's working fine so far, with relevant variables listed first.

```
private ImageView sphere;
private AnimationDrawable sphereAnimation;
private AnimationDrawable sphereResume;
private AnimationDrawable activeAnimation;
private Drawable currentFrame;
private Drawable checkFrame;
private int frameIndex;

private void pause()
{
    looping = false;
    sphereResume = new AnimationDrawable();
    activeAnimation.stop();
    currentFrame = activeAnimation.getCurrent();

    frameLoop:
    for(int i = 0; i < sphereAnimation.getNumberOfFrames(); i++)
    {
        checkFrame = activeAnimation.getFrame(i);

        if(checkFrame == currentFrame)
        {
            frameIndex = i;
            for(int k = frameIndex; k < activeAnimation.getNumberOfFrames(); k++)
            {
                Drawable frame = activeAnimation.getFrame(k);
                sphereResume.addFrame(frame, 50);
            }
            for(int k = 0; k < frameIndex; k++)
            {
                Drawable frame = activeAnimation.getFrame(k);
                sphereResume.addFrame(frame, 50);
            }
            activeAnimation = sphereResume;
            sphere.setImageDrawable(activeAnimation);
            sphere.invalidate();
            break frameLoop;
        }
    }
}

private void play()
{
    looping = false;
    activeAnimation.setOneShot(true);
    activeAnimation.start();
}

private void stop()
{
    looping = false;
    activeAnimation.stop();
    activeAnimation = sphereAnimation;
    sphere.setImageDrawable(activeAnimation);
}

private void loop()
{
    looping = true;
    stopSoundEffect();
    activeAnimation.setOneShot(false);
    activeAnimation.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete code, what is the value of sphere animation here?

Answer (score 0):

The method by Zorbert Crenshaw is Nice, but it's complicated.

I have another solution.(Need surround  with try/catch because reflection is unsafe).

you can call ***getCurFrameFromAnimationDrawable*** to save the current frame before stop Animation, and call ***setCurFrameToAnimationDrawable*** to start from any frame.

'30L' should be replaced your param of duration.

```
private int getCurFrameFromAnimationDrawable(AnimationDrawable drawable){
    try {
        Field mCurFrame = drawable.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCurFrame");
        mCurFrame.setAccessible(true);
        return  mCurFrame.getInt(drawable);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(AnimTool.class.getName(), "getCurFrameFromAnimationDrawable: Exception");
        return 0;
    }
}

private void setCurFrameToAnimationDrawable(AnimationDrawable drawable, int curFrame){
    try {
        Field mCurFrame = drawable.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCurFrame");
        mCurFrame.setAccessible(true);
        mCurFrame.setInt(drawable, curFrame);
        Class[] param = new Class[]{Runnable.class, long.class};
        Method method = Drawable.class.getDeclaredMethod("scheduleSelf", param);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(drawable, drawable, 30L);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(AnimTool.class.getName(), "setCurFrameToAnimationDrawable: Exception");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer to the question. But it might help with the other one. To pause and resume AnimationDrawable, simply customize it and handle with only one variable.

```
class CustomAnimationDrawable1() : AnimationDrawable() {

private var finished = false
private var animationFinishListener: AnimationFinishListener? = null
private var isPause = false
private var currentFrame = 0

fun setFinishListener(animationFinishListener: AnimationFinishListener?) {
    this.animationFinishListener = animationFinishListener
}

interface AnimationFinishListener {
    fun onAnimationFinished()
}


override fun selectDrawable(index: Int): Boolean {
    val ret = if (isPause) {
        super.selectDrawable(currentFrame)
    } else {
        super.selectDrawable(index)
    }

    if (!isPause) {
        currentFrame = index
        if (index == numberOfFrames - 1) {
            if (!finished && ret && !isOneShot) {
                finished = true
                if (animationFinishListener != null) animationFinishListener!!.onAnimationFinished()
            }
        }
    }
    return ret
}

fun pause() {
    isPause = true
}

fun resume() {
    isPause = false
}
```

}