# How i pause and resume AnimationDrawable in Android?

Tags: animationdrawable

```
    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a1), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a2), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a3), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a4), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a5), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a6), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a7), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a8), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a9), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a10), 1000);
    animation.setOneShot(true);

    sayac = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sayac);
    sayac.setImageDrawable(animation);

    animation.start();


     // play the animation when i push the play button
     play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    // pause the animation when i push pause button...
    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

I want to pause and resume `AnimationDrawable`. But I can't. How can I do this?

Or can I do the same animation with `ObjectAnimator` or others?

If I can do the same animation with `ObjectAnimator` how can I do this? Is there any lesson or example?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [AnimationDrawable Pause ?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10755416)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AnimationDrawable Pause ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755416/animationdrawable-pause)