# Continue Animation Into Sub Activity

Tags: java, android

I want to provide an animated background for my app for all activities. I am using the following guide:

https://medium.com/@joonasm.kauppinen/animated-gradient-background-on-android-part-1-2-82f378257610

It works nicely, but whenever I go into a sub activity, the animation starts over. I want to be able to continue the animation from main activity into sub activity and back. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Make Sure you have Included just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean by sub Activity? please post some code so we can reproduce the problem and help

Comment: It is exactly the same as in the guide. When I move from the main activity to any sub activity using `startActivity()` I want the animation to continue from the point in the main activity. By default, it starts the animation from the beginning. I also want to be able to return to the main activity from sub activity and resume the animation.

Comment: If the background is persistent and you want it to be the same for all the "sub activities", set this animation only to the parent activity and remove background of other activities to be translucent or transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Even if reflection is used to access and set current frame. It will not work in the case above. Even if the `AnimationDrawable` was created programmatically and it was shared between both of the activities. It will not work either. Some developers suggested using a background on main activity and suggested that it would be shared on child activities. That is not how activities work. Even if there was a way to achieve the sharing of animation, the app would have out of memory issues.

TL;DR It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to have a single activity and add a fragment for the 1st screen. Then when you want to navigate away (what you do now with `startActivity`) you should instead replace the fragment.

Something like this:

```
class MainActivity: Activity()  {


  onCreate(...) {
           
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      add1stFragment()
  }

  fun add1stFragment(){
     supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, LandingFragment())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()

  }

}

class LandingFragment : Fragment() {

   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
      // inflate layout with the contents of 1st screen
   }

   fun add2ndFragment(){
     supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, AlternativeFragment())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()

  }
}


class AlternativeFragment : Fragment() {
  fun  onCreateView(...){...
}
}
```

res/layout/activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="4dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:title="TITLE" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">


        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now the toolbar and background are the same for both screens, because they belong to the activity. While the screen contents belong to the different fragments.

The only downside is that if you rotate the screen the animation would start again. If you want that to continue from where it was you can use a couple things, but they will depend on how exactly you're doing the animation.

Unfortunately I tried giving a quick look at AnimationDrawable and I don't see how to make it jump to a specific point in its animation, nor how to get the current progress. Otherwise it would looks something like this (in case you used a different animation method):

```
class MainActivity: Activity {

 private var animDrawable : AnimatedDrawable? =null 
onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       animDrawable = root_layout.background as? AnimationDrawable
      
      fromIndex = getIndex(savedInstanceState)
     

      add1stFragment()
  }


   override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putInt("POSITION",animDrawable.getPosition)
    }

     

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        startAnimation(fromIndex) // extract the current position and start playing from there
    }
```

Make sure to check the background of your fragments is transparent. And optionally, set `AppBarLayout` opacity with `android:alpha="0.5"`. It's questionable taste but it will allow the background to shine through.

Edit: so there is a very roundabout way to get the current position and resume from a given position, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13613613/2754856

Also, just figured out that you shouldn't call AnimationDrawable::start from onCreate: file:///home/fabiomint/bin/astudio/android-sdk/docs/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#start() and made some edits to match that.

Edit 2 for handling multiple activities:

It also works for screen rotation. It's not as good as using the same animation on the same activity, because the act of pausing/resuming animation on a different activity has a side effect of making a copy of the animation with the different frames with switched orders.

As I mentioned above, having a single activity is my 1st suggestion. The 2nd one is using another animation technique for this, `AnimationDrawable` is a pain to work with. `ObjectAnimator` is more friendly and it's possible to build gradient animation with it, but it can't animate shapes and other things that I believe only AnimationDrawable supports, like animated vectors.

make a singleton or global variable:

```
var activityBackground = PausableAnimationDrawable()
```

then on each of your activities do

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        findViewById<View>(R.id.root)
            ?.let {

                it.background = activityBackground.getAnimation(this)
            }
        activityBackground.resume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        activityBackground.pause()
    }
```

```
class PausableAnimationDrawable {

    private var activeAnimation: AnimationDrawable? = null
    private var animation: AnimationDrawable? = null

    private var indexFrame: Int = 0

    fun pause() {

        indexFrame = getCurrentIndex()
    }

    fun resume() {
        activeAnimation?.start()
        activeAnimation?.setVisible(true, false)
    }

    fun getAnimation(context: Context): AnimationDrawable? {

        if (animation == null) {
            animation = getNewAnimation(context)
        }

        activeAnimation = getReindexedAnimation(animation, indexFrame)

        return activeAnimation
    }

    private fun getReindexedAnimation(
        animation: AnimationDrawable?,
        indexFrame: Int
    ): AnimationDrawable? {

        val animation = animation ?: return null

        return AnimationDrawable()
            .also { newDrawable ->
                for (i in indexFrame..animation.numberOfFrames) {
                    animation.getFrame(i)
                        ?.let {
                            newDrawable.addFrame(it, animation.getDuration(i))
                        }
                }
                for (i in 0 until indexFrame) {
                    animation.getFrame(i)
                        ?.let {
                            newDrawable.addFrame(it, animation.getDuration(i))
                        }
                }
            }

    }

    private fun getNewAnimation(context: Context): AnimationDrawable? {
        return context.applicationContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient)
            ?.let { it as? AnimationDrawable }
            ?.also { it.setVisible(false, false) }
    }


    private fun getCurrentIndex(): Int {

        for (i in 0..(activeAnimation?.numberOfFrames ?: 0)) {
            if (activeAnimation?.getFrame(i) == activeAnimation?.current) {
                Timber.d("*** Frame %s match", i)
                return (i + indexFrame) % (activeAnimation?.numberOfFrames ?: 0)

            } else {
                Timber.d("*** Frame %s no match", i)
            }
        }

        return 0
    }


}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply to my question and all the effort you put into it. Thanks. Though, this does not answer my question. My question is regarding the switch from one activity to another. I will not change the whole design of my app into a single activity design. This is not feasible nor favorable.

Comment: Understandable. Then your best bet is to follow my suggestion for when rotating activities, the key difference is passing the frame number forward from one activity to the next, and then pass it backwards when closing second activity. I find this interesting so may create a fully working project tomorrow but it's too late here now.

Comment: While none of the answers here helped me, and I know now that what I want is not possible. I have decided to award @Fabio the bounty for all the time and effort he put in trying to help me out.

Comment: thx @Jack for the bounty, though I'm still interested in seeing other angles to this challenge. Did I understand the problem right or maybe I missed something?

Comment: I have tried your edit2 code above and I could not continue the animation into any of the sub activities. I do not know if you have tested that code or not. If you actually tried the code out, maybe you can provide a sample project that works. Then, everyone will benefit. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

your best shot is to have your main activity with the background then make your next activity's background transparent such that on launching your next activity,you still see the background of your previous main activity

so you make the next activity transparent by setting the below theme on to your activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

And then set a transparent background to your next activity like so

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background = "any tranparent image/color"  >
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try passing to the child activity the important values of the animation (i.e angle, milliseconds elapsed, etc), and then start the new animation on the child activity with those values. That way your animation will seem like it's resuming.